# Apply theme dynamically on Onsen UI

Tags: onsen-ui

I'm working on a customizable application based on Onsen UI. I'd like to know if Onsen UI exposes a method (or if there is some way to hack around it) to set a theme dynamically, in the same way components.onsenui.io does for previewing a generated theme.

What I'd like to accomplish is that the user can select the theme colors for his own application. So i would need some way to set the ui colors using Javascript instead of downloading a static/generated theme.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, Onsen UI doesn't provide APIs to change theme dynamically.

Changing or editing the stylesheet programmatically is the way to do this.